# Excel export (xlsx) error Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, memorystream, closedxml

I am facing System.OutOfMemoryException while exporting .xlsx file from ASP .Net this is happening while writing the data into memory stream.

```
protected void ExportExcel(string strWorkbookName, DataTable dt)
{
    try
    {
        dt.TableName = strWorkbookName;

        using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
        {
            wb.Worksheets.Add(dt);
            Response.Clear();
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.Charset = "";
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + strWorkbookName + ".xlsx");
            using (MemoryStream MyMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {                    
                wb.SaveAs(MyMemoryStream);                    
                MyMemoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
                Response.Flush();
                //HttpContext.Current.Response.SuppressContent = true;  // Gets or sets a value indicating whether to send HTTP content to the client.
                //HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
                Response.End();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        string errorMessage = string.Empty;

        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Exception is being occurred on line `wb.SaveAs(MyMemoryStream);`

`XLWorkbook` class belong to ClosedXML.dll, v0.69.1.0 library for exporting excel.

Reference: https://closedxml.codeplex.com/

anyone any idea!?!

How to resolve this?

Comment: How big is your DataTable?

Answer (score 0):

A few years ago, I wrote an "Export to Excel" C# class, and faced the same issue with large data sets.

The solution was to use the `OpenXmlWriter` library, so your code isn't attempting to put together the entire Excel file in memory, before writing it our to a file.

In your example, simply take your DataTable, `dt`, and pass it to my library, and the problem goes away.  You'll have a real .xlsx file, created using Microsoft's  OpenXML library.

```
try
{
    dt.TableName = strWorkbookName;
    CreateExcelFile.CreateExcelDocument(dt, "YourExcelFilename.xlsx");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //  Handle any execptions..
}
```

Or, as you're including this in an ASP.Net application, you can get my library to save the Excel file directly to your page's Response:

```
CreateExcelFile.CreateExcelDocument(dt, "YourExcelFilename.xlsx", Response);
```

My source code is available to download (for free) here:

[Export to Excel](http://www.mikesknowledgebase.com/pages/CSharp/ExportToExcel.htm)

Comment: By doing this page gets refresh no data is downloaded.

Comment: Set a breakpoint, make sure "dt" does contain some data before calling my C# library.

Comment: I have confirmed it has 213221 rows and 18 columns